# MySQL better practice, one big table or better divide to separate tables, using Java hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

My goal is store sport like football, basketball ,hockey and etc. matches in MySQL database. Table fields like country, league, home team, away team, result and etc. it is not dependence by sport type. My predictions is approximately 500 records per day for each sport type. So about 500*365 ~ approximately 200 000 records per year for one sport type. My goal is store 6 sport types. So if I store in one table I will get 1 200 000/records per year. What is better practice create one table `match` with field `sport_type` and store 1 mln records per year in one table or divide in separate tables like `match_football` and store about 200 000 records per year per table.

And other questions is i want use java and hibernate to work with this data. So if i good understand if I decide to create separate tables I must create different java classes as hibernate entities with some fields.

Comment: [normalisation](http://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: You can always go to several tables, but making reports etcetera is much easier when you postpone that. And one may utilize views and such to prepare a transition to single tables. Assumedly a normalized main table, as opposed to have several identical tables per sport.

Comment: Thanks, I understood your idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to:
1. Store all in 1 table
2. Partition table. You can add filed year or quarter and partition that table on that key.
3. When you search inside always use that key as criteria
This is a tip .. to further investigate chck http://www.chrismoos.com/2010/01/31/mysql-partitioning-tables-with-millions-of-rows